# Static Methods As A Wrapper

Tags: unit-testing, static

If you have a class called MyClass with a set of public methods; MethodA, MethodB and MethodC.  And in some locations of an application you only need a single method from MyClass, for example:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.MethodA();
```

To simplify the above I would like to create a single static method that wraps the above lines of coded.  I am planning to write unit tests against MethodA.  In my unit test MethodA interacts with an interface that is implemented using a mock framework (I think this is called Inversion of Control).

Is it safe to assume that by testing MethodA that the static method (wrapper method) is also being tested indirectly.  I am assuming the actually implementation for the interface used in MethodA is also being tested.

Or should I not implemented the static method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, don't do that!

Static methods used like you want to do are the exact opposite of inversion of control / dependency injection, and as such, are a bad practice.
What you want to do is inject into all classes that need a `MyClass` an interface to it (either injected through the constructor or a setter, manually or using a IoC framework like Spring).

If you wrap your lines of code in a static method that you call from another class, then you'll couple the specific implementation of `MyClass` too tightly, which is the opposite of what you want to achieve.

But to answer your more specific question, it's *never* safe to assume the code is tested by another test, unless it actually is. What I mean is: if there is NO test that go through the static method, then it's not covered. Even if you may think it's trivial, don't forget it may be refactored later, and no test will indicate it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not safe to assume the wrapper method is also being tested.  There is code in the wrapper method, and that code could have a defect in it, so you'll need to write unit tests against that code as well.